# Meu live serve não funciona no modo "inspecionar"

Tags: html, css

quando estou atualizando o código de tela normal ele funciona corretamente, porém se uso o requisito "Inspecionar" ele sai do ar
PS: meu código tá zoado pois ainda sou iniciante no mundo da programação, ainda estou treinando os comandos

meu codigo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Landing Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@300&family=Solway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="title" >
            <h1><img class=logo-x src="Logos/Sem título.png" alt=""></h1>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="menu-bar">
        <label for="menu-bar" class="fa-bars"></label>
        <nav class="nav-bar">
            <ul>
                <a href="#"><li >Home</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Serviços</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Contato</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Sobre</li></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <a href="#"class="login"><li>Entrar</li></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    
    <main >
        <aside>
            <h1 class="titulo-empresa">Monte sua empresa aqui</h1>
            
        </aside>
        <article class="paragrafo">
            <h2 class="paragrafo-titulo">Desenvolvimeto, inovação, segurança e confiabilidade</h2>
            <p class="paragrafo-comentario" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima aperiam nisi vitae quod quos corporis debitis, quam sapiente ab autem laboriosam, deserunt non ducimus aut nulla officia nobis dicta dolorum.</p>
        </article>
    </main>
    <div class="logos">
      <section >
        <img class="logos" src="Logos/JP Morgan.svg" alt="Logo">
        <img class="logos" src="Logos/Tinder.svg" alt="logo Tinder">
        <img class="logos"src="Logos/Samsung.svg" alt="Logo Samsung">
        <img class="logos"src="Logos/Verizon.svg" alt="logo Verizon">
        <img class="logos"src="Logos/Visa.svg" alt="logo Visa">
        <img class="logos"src="Logos/Walmart.svg" alt="Logo Walmart">
    </section>  
    </div>
    
    <section >
        <aside class="img1" >
          <figure>
            <img src="img/Spense.png" alt="imagem">
            <h4>Lorem</h4>
            <figcaption class="img_x">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, nulla esse voluptas ipsa soluta corporis. Aliquam explicabo dolor quam sed earum officiis! Laboriosam sit doloribus ex in eaque, ab sunt.</figcaption>
        </figure>  
        </aside>
        <aside class="img2">
            <figure >
            <img  src="img/YelpCamp.png" alt="imagem">
            <h4 >Lorem</h4>
            <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente incidunt rerum quia maiores, excepturi cupiditate repellendus doloremque consequatur odit cumque, sequi explicabo, dolorum quae architecto ea reprehenderit ullam sunt consequuntur!</figcaption>
        </figure>
        </aside>
    </section>

    <section class="historia">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto esse, corrupti sapiente non, fuga asperiores perferendis atque eius nisi repellat autem quod doloribus? Voluptatem nam voluptas inventore doloribus, ipsam quos.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Incidunt recusandae mollitia nesciunt odio praesentium, doloremque odit minima ipsam aliquam sapiente impedit corporis a animi error exercitationem laborum quaerat? Omnis ipsum enim explicabo dolorem, voluptatum ullam. Eveniet iste sint fugiat cupiditate!</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae, molestiae!</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non cupiditate tempore alias ullam. Iure temporibus officia blanditiis ab maiores quod quae corporis rerum incidunt asperiores modi, culpa, itaque pariatur a.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus delectus similique, nobis iusto omnis iste. Pariatur facilis dignissimos ab nisi illo excepturi odio cumque maiores sapiente officia mollitia, corrupti non molestias tenetur soluta quae architecto quod autem maxime. Sit temporibus perferendis amet reiciendis placeat quidem ipsam, sapiente dicta nam expedita.
        </p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h1>Interessado em trabalhar comigo?</h1>
        <p>Atendo em todas as plataformas presentes</p>
        <div>
            <form>
                <input class="input-final" type="submit" value="Vamos conversar!">
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <h3>Isabelle Nascimento</h3>
        <aside>
         <img src="Social Icons/icons8-github.svg" alt="incon">
        <img src="Social Icons/icons8-instagram.svg" alt="incon">
        <img src="Social Icons/icons8-linkedin-circled.svg" alt="incon">
        </aside>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@300&family=Solway&display=swap');

/* opçoes de cores */
:root{
   --black:#000000;
   --yeollow:#F5F60C;
   --gray:#808080; 
   --blue:#0F62D9;
   --softblue:#75F8FA;
   --azul-gradiente: radial-gradient(circle at 4.55% 104.17%, #006156 0, #006160 3.57%, #00616a 7.14%, #006173 10.71%, #00617c 14.29%, #006084 17.86%, #005f8c 21.43%, #005d91 25%, #005c96 28.57%, #005999 32.14%, #00579b 35.71%, #00549b 39.29%, #02509a 42.86%, #324c97 46.43%, #484893 50%, #59438e 53.57%, #673e87 57.14%, #72397f 60.71%, #7c3577 64.29%, #84306e 67.86%, #8a2c64 71.43%, #8e295a 75%, #912850 78.57%, #922846 82.14%, #922a3c 85.71%, #912d32 89.29%, #8e3129 92.86%, #8a3620 96.43%, #853a17 100%);
}
/* todo o texto  */
*{
   text-transform: capitalize;
   font-family: 'Solway', serif ;
   margin:0; padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* corpo  */
body {
    
    /* max-width: 1200px; */
    /* margin: 0 auto; */
    color: white;
    background-image: var(--azul-gradiente);
 }

 /* dentro de header */
 header{
   background-image: var(--black);
   /* position: fixed; */
   top:0; left: 0;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-around;
   align-items: center;
   width: 100vw;
   box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}
.menu_item, .menu-principal{
   display: flex;

}

 nav li{
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 1.5em;
   font-size: 20px;
 }
 .nav-bar{
   margin-left: 15%;
 }
 header input{
   display: none;
 }
 header label{
   font-size: 3rem;
   color: var(--blue);
   cursor: pointer;
   visibility: hidden;
 }
 a{
   color: white;
 }
 a:hover{
   color: #5FB8FF;
   transition: 0.3s all;
 }
 .login{
   border: 6px solid #5FB8FF;
   border-radius: 20px;
   padding: 10px;
}
.login:hover {
   background-color: #5FB8FF;
   color: white;
}
header #title{
   flex-direction: column;
   font-weight: 500;
   color: var(--blue);
}

 /* fim de dentro do header  */

 main aside{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-around;
   margin-top: 5vh;
 }
.titulo-empresa{
   margin-bottom: 5%;
   font-weight:700;
   font-size: 60px;
   display: flex
}
.paragrafo, .paragrafo-titulo, .paragrafo-comentario{
   display: flex;
   margin: 1em 2em 1em 2em;
   align-items: center;
}

.logos{
   text-align: center;
   padding: 2%;
   justify-content: space-between;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   
}
figure figcaption{
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
   /* position: relative; */
   /* display: flex; */
}
.img1{
   float: right;
   width: 50%;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
}
.img2{
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
}
.historia{
   margin-top: 45%;
}
.input-final{
   border: 6px solid #5FB8FF;
   border-radius: 20px;
   padding: 10px;
   font-family: 'Solway', serif ; 
}
.input-final:hover {
   background-color: #5FB8FF;
   color: white;
}
footer{
   background-color: #80808086;
   margin-top: 5%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Olá,

Você pode tentar usar outro navegador ou tentar reinstalar o plugin.

Até.